# Batch File - IF statement issue

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

Hello to all my fellow StackOverflow members!  I am trying to setup a somewhat basic script to help with checking user account details on a domain controller in a domain oriented Corp environment.  One of the IT Service managers setup a very watered down script that basically just runs the following command:

net user  /domain

I have tried to build a better script since we use this in so many of our customer environments it cuts down on guess work and time overall.  The problem is at the end of the script I setup a direct back to the top of the script with a y/n prompt.. however, if you fail to press Y or N (case insensitive) and rather press j or 3 for example the script terminates.  I have been extremely unsuccessful in setting up a basic error handling routine that states if the reported value is neither y nor n, echo a simple error string and then repeat the prompt.  The following is my code for the setup (I have removed the previously attempts at setting up the looped routine for the y/n values.  I have changed the values of the actual paths to each GOTO section so as not to share customer oriented information.

```
@ECHO OFF

:Start
SET uname=
cls

IF "%userdomain%"=="D1" GOTO 1
IF "%userdomain%"=="D2" GOTO 2
IF "%userdomain%"=="D3" GOTO 3
IF "%userdomain%"=="D4" GOTO 4

:1
ECHO You are on the D1 domain (%userdomain%)
ECHO Usernames should be in the format of firstname.lastname
ECHO.
SET /P uname=Username: 
IF "%uname%"=="" GOTO Error
net user %uname% /domain
GOTO Request

:2
ECHO You are on the D2 Domain (%userdomain%)
ECHO Username format varies based on the creation of the ID.
ECHO.
SET /P uname=Username: 
IF "%uname%"=="" GOTO Error
net user %uname% /domain
GOTO Request

:3
ECHO You are on the D3 Domain (%userdomain%)
ECHO Usernames are formatted as First Initial Last Name (auser)
ECHO.
SET /P uname=Username: 
IF "%uname%"=="" GOTO Error
net user %uname% /domain
GOTO Request

:4
ECHO You are on the D4 Domain (%userdomain%)
ECHO Usernames are formatted as First Initial Last Name (auser)
ECHO.
SET /P uname=Username: 
IF "%uname%"=="" GOTO Error
net user %uname% /domain
GOTO Request

:Error
ECHO.
ECHO Username was left blank, please enter a valid username and try again
ECHO.
TIMEOUT /T 5
GOTO Start

:Request
ECHO.
SET /P resp=Do you want to perform another lookup Y/N?
IF /I "%resp%"=="y" GOTO Start
IF /I "%resp%"=="n" exit
```

In the :Request section above I tried using IF /I NOT and IF NOT /I to begin the statement, as well as using a true false oriented value setting a variable to true, then making the statement say if not y if not n set variable to false, then using if false, repeat the loop, so far hitting any key other than y or n just exits the prompt.

Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: You could just put a `GOTO Request` after `IF /I "%resp%"=="n" exit`.  But using `CHOICE` is probably the better option.

Comment: Because the command first being run IS the net user command, the end portion of the file asks if you wanna run the command again.  As detailed in the above I didn't state the issue IS the command itself, simply the issue is with the file in which the command runs within.

Comment: The question is worded accordingly and doesn't need to be changed, it was very specifically designed.  However.. I would change the title other than I can't seem to find a way to do so from any of the menus or areas on the site.

Comment: Sorry I missed that it was a valid link, title has been edited

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong command, when only known inputs are required, use the `choice.exe` utility instead:

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF

:Start
CLS
ECHO You are on the D%USERDOMAIN:~-1% domain (%USERDOMAIN%)
ECHO Usernames should be in the format of firstname.lastname
ECHO(
SET "uname="
SET /P "uname=Username: "
IF NOT DEFINED uname GOTO Error
NET USER %uname% /DOMAIN
GOTO Request

:Error
ECHO(
ECHO Username was left blank, please enter a valid username and try again
ECHO(
TIMEOUT /T 5
GOTO Start

:Request
ECHO(
CHOICE /M "Do you want to perform another lookup"
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO Start
```

---

Additional example with message before closing.

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF

:Start
CLS
ECHO You are on the D%USERDOMAIN:~-1% domain (%USERDOMAIN%)
ECHO Usernames should be in the format of firstname.lastname
ECHO(
SET "uname="
SET /P "uname=Username: "
IF NOT DEFINED uname GOTO Error
NET USER %uname% /DOMAIN
GOTO Request

:Error
ECHO(
ECHO Username was left blank, please enter a valid username and try again
ECHO(
TIMEOUT /T 5
GOTO Start

:Request
ECHO(
CHOICE /M "Do you want to perform another lookup"
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO Start
ECHO(
ECHO Thank you and goodbye.
ECHO Press any key to exit. . .
TIMEOUT /T -1 >NUL
```

Comment: So just making sure I understand, the CHOICE utility specifically asks a Y/N based request, and if anything OTHER than the Y/N are entered, it fails, else goto the start?

The problem with that would be if the user selects N, the utility should exit, and if Y and only then, goto start.  The bigger question is, how can I do a custom error like I did for the blank username portion rather than a canned response, while still using the same recommended utility?

Comment: The choice command by default offers a language specific `Y|N` (Yes|No), option. So in Germany for example it would offer  `J|N` (Ja|Nein). The code I've provided will `GOTO Start` if the first option was chosen, which is what you wanted. Any valid answer, which was not the first option, will step over the `GOTO Start` line and as there are no more commands after that, the script will end. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?`, press `[ENTER]` and read the usage information. I've provided an additional example with some commands, added to provide an error message for you too.

Comment: So going over the /? documentation helped me understand the choices and the use of the choices utility.  However, if the user presses an invalid key rather than display an error message, I simply want to recycle the original :Request portion AFTER a custom error message such as "Invalid key selection", then have it loop back to CHOICE, rather than simply have it play an audible tone.  The way it functions on the exit works fine, also the GOTO Start portion if YES is detected.